# How to pull data with JSON?

Tags: php, json

JSON Example: http://prntscr.com/fl2btu

[odds] I want to list all the data in the section.

```
foreach ($json1 as $v){
for($i=0; $i<=count($v); $i++){
    echo ????????
}
```

}
What should I write where are the question marks?

`echo $v->feeds->extra->bets[$i];`

I get an error in the summer.

Comment: `feeds` is an array and doesn't contain a field named 'extra'. If at all, it should be `$v->feeds[0]->extra->bets[$i]`. Also it is not obvious what part of the json your variable `$v` is. It could very well be, that $v is already the 'feeds' object. In which case it should work with `$v[0]->extra->bets[$i]`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately, gave an error.

Comment: As I said, from your question alone it is hard to tell where in the json object tree your variable `$v` actually is. Also if the 'feeds' field has sibling fields it could be one of them that throws an error during the foreach loop.

Comment: Thank you for your reply to ok, take good care of yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($json as $v) {
    foreach($v->feeds as $feed) {
        foreach ($feed->extra->bets as $bet) {
             var_dump($bet->event->odds);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\bets\index.php on line 12
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\bets\index.php on line 12
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$feeds in C:\xampp\htdocs\bets\index.php on line 12
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\bets\index.php on line 12

Thank you for the reply gave such an error.

Comment: try with $v['feeds'] instead. as you have told, it is hard to tell what is your "json" object.